# Flash on iPad JS

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, mobile-safari

Now we all are aware that there is no Flash supported on the iPad.

But my question is does the iPad return some kind of error which we can capture in Javascript. I know one option is just to detect iPad from UA string. but wanted to know what can be captured in JS when Flash is called , either as a direct .swf request or within some containing html file?

Comment: Flash is a plugin, so not sure why that would fire off a JS error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Develop the page as if Flash wasn't available.  Detect the presence of Flash with JavaScript and add it in during page load.

Comment: Thx..actually i am aware of that..But thing is in our app, there are almost 3000+ flash already created called in some jsps and now on the iPad, i need to detect whether those jsps have the swf called within them..Indirectly i am trying to understand if Flash returns any error status message or something which JS can capture..

Comment: Flash would need to be installed for Flash to return anything.